# How to add child ScrollViews?

Tags: android, touch, focus, android-scrollview

I have an outer HorizontalScrollView which lets me scroll 3 pages in my app. On the 3rd (rightmost) page I have a screen which contains a HorizontalScrollView within the outer scrollview.

However, when I touch the child scrollview, its the outer scrollview that gets the touch events. How can I ensure that the child scrollview gets the events?

```
   +---screen--+
   |+----------+----------+----------+
   |+  outer   |          |+---------+---------+---------+
   |+  scroll  |          ||  child scroll     |         |
   |+          |          |+--------++---------+---------+
   |+          |          +----------+                 <>
   |+          |          + Textview +
   |+----------+----------+----------+
   +-----------+                   <>
```

Here's the code that I borrowed which extends HorizontalScrollView:

```
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;

public class CustomHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView implements
    OnTouchListener, OnGestureListener
{

  private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE       = 300;

  private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 300;
  private static final int SWIPE_PAGE_ON_FACTOR     = 5;

  private GestureDetector  gestureDetector;
  private int              scrollTo                 = 0;
  private int              maxItem                  = 0;
  private int              activeItem               = 0;
  private float            prevScrollX              = 0;
  private boolean          start                    = true;
  private int              itemWidth                = 0;
  private float            currentScrollX;
  private boolean          flingDisable             = true;
  public int tag;

  public CustomHorizontalScrollView( Context context )
  {
    super( context );
    setLayoutParams( new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ) );
  }

  public CustomHorizontalScrollView( Context context, int maxItem, int itemWidth )
  {
    this( context );
    this.maxItem = maxItem;
    this.itemWidth = itemWidth;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector( this );
    this.setOnTouchListener( this );
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event )
  {
    if( gestureDetector.onTouchEvent( event ) )
    {
      return true;
    }
    Boolean returnValue = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent( event );

    int x = (int) event.getRawX();

    switch( event.getAction() )
    {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if( start )
        {
          this.prevScrollX = x;
          start = false;
        }
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        start = true;
        this.currentScrollX = x;
        int minFactor = itemWidth / SWIPE_PAGE_ON_FACTOR;

        if( ( this.prevScrollX - this.currentScrollX ) > minFactor )
        {
          if( activeItem < maxItem - 1 )
            activeItem = activeItem + 1;

        }
        else 
        if( ( this.currentScrollX - this.prevScrollX ) > minFactor )
        {
          if( activeItem > 0 )
            activeItem = activeItem - 1;
        }
        System.out.printf( "SV%d horizontal : %d\n", tag, activeItem );
        scrollTo = activeItem * itemWidth;
        this.smoothScrollTo( scrollTo, 0 );
        returnValue = true;
        break;
    }
    return returnValue;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onFling( MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
      float velocityY )
  {
    if( flingDisable )
      return false;
    boolean returnValue = false;
    float ptx1 = 0, ptx2 = 0;
    if( e1 == null || e2 == null )
      return false;
    ptx1 = e1.getX();
    ptx2 = e2.getX();
    // right to left

    if( ptx1 - ptx2 > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
        && Math.abs( velocityX ) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY )
    {
      if( activeItem < maxItem - 1 )
        activeItem = activeItem + 1;

      returnValue = true;

    }
    else if( ptx2 - ptx1 > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
        && Math.abs( velocityX ) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY )
    {
      if( activeItem > 0 )
        activeItem = activeItem - 1;

      returnValue = true;
    }
    scrollTo = activeItem * itemWidth;
    this.smoothScrollTo( 0, scrollTo );
    return returnValue;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onDown( MotionEvent e )
  {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void onLongPress( MotionEvent e )
  {
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onScroll( MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
      float distanceY )
  {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void onShowPress( MotionEvent e )
  {
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onSingleTapUp( MotionEvent e )
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here's how I construct my layouts. I add the mBaseLinearLayout to the 3rd page of my outer scroll view. I can then scroll to this 3rd page. Once the 3rd page is on the screen I then want to be able to scroll the child scroll view. It should scroll off the left of the screen while the TextView control stays stationary on the screen.

```
// Base layout is only one page wide but it has keypad scroll layout that extends over 3 pages..
mBaseLinearLayout = new LinearLayout( mActivity );
mBaseLinearLayout.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( ContextActivity.screenWidth, ContextActivity.screenHeight ) );
mBaseLinearLayout.setOrientation( LinearLayout.VERTICAL );
mBaseLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(  Color.YELLOW );

mKeypadScrollView = new CustomHorizontalScrollView( mActivity, 3, ContextActivity.screenWidth );
mKeypadScrollView.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1 ) );
mKeypadScrollView.tag = 69;

// Add 3 pages of buttons to the page layout..
mPageLinearLayout = new LinearLayout( mActivity );
mPageLinearLayout.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( ContextActivity.screenWidth * nNumPages, ContextActivity.screenHeight ) );

GridLayout page1 = CreateAlphaPage( 0 ); 
GridLayout page2 = CreateAlphaPage( 1 );
GridLayout page3 = CreateAlphaPage( 2 );

mPageLinearLayout.addView( page1 );
mPageLinearLayout.addView( page2 );
mPageLinearLayout.addView( page3 );

// Add scroll view to the top of the base layout and a text view underneath.
mKeypadScrollView.addView( mPageLinearLayout );

TextView tv = new TextView( mActivity );
tv.setX( 0 );
tv.setWidth( ContextActivity.screenWidth );
tv.setHeight( ContextActivity.screenHeight );
tv.setBackgroundColor( Color.MAGENTA );
tv.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1 ) );

mBaseLinearLayout.addView( mKeypadScrollView );
mBaseLinearLayout.addView( tv );
```

Comment: Have you tried OnDirectionScrollView?
https://gist.github.com/XinyueZ/f1831db4a0273c5f259f

Comment: @TeeTracker: I haven't tried it. I'd like to understand and fix what I do have if possible though. It will be my misunderstanding about events and layouts that really needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself. The solution was to create a ScrollStopListener interface so that when the extremes of the scrollview are reached, I can stop the outer scrollview from being scrollable. This lets the inner scrollview receive the events. Obviously this solution isn't going to work for everybody but it works fine for me and I can continue working on my app. I'm sure somebody will reply with a better solution over time.